# C# string concatenation and string interning

Tags: c#, .net, string

When performing string concatentation of an existing string in the intern pool, is a new string entered into the intern pool or is a reference returned to the existing string in the intern pool? According to this article, String.Concat and StringBuilder will insert new string instances into the intern pool?

http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/09/27/4472.aspx

Can anyone explain how concatenation works with the intern pool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create new strings, they will not automatically be put into the intern pool, unless you concatenate constants compile-time, in which case the compiler will create one string result and intern that as part of the JIT process.

Answer (score 0):

You can see whether a string has been interned by calling `String.IsInterned`. The call will return a new string that is either a reference to an interned string equal to the string that was passed as an argument, or `null` if the string was not interned.