# object.ReferenceEquals behave differently

Tags: c#

```
string x = "alok b";

string y = "alok b";

string z = "alok";

//y += x.Replace(y, string.Empty);
z += " b";

Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(x,y));
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(y, z));
```

How is first line is printing `true` and second `false`?

and changing to below statement is printing `true`.

```
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(y,string.Intern(z)));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010/c-sharp-string-concatenation-and-string-interning

Comment: The first two are string literals which are automatically added to the string-pool, which saves memory since the same string can be used multiple times. That's why `object.ReferenceEquals(x,y)` returns `true`. Then you are using a method to modify an existing string(actually you are creating a new since strings are immutable). All runtime strings are not stored in the string-pool. That's why `object.ReferenceEquals(y, z)` returns `false`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter seems fair explanation, and string.Intern(z) also gives the same value (i.e. "alok b") but using this cause to print true, why?

Comment: @KyloRen: because [`String.Intern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern(v=vs.110).aspx) works in that way: it returns _"the system's reference to str, if it is interned; otherwise, a new reference to a string with the value of str."_ In this case that string is already in the pool(because you've used `string y = "alok b"` which is a string literal), so you get the same reference to it as return value.

Comment: @TimSchmelter when you say system's reference do you mean the reference in the string-pool you mentioned in your above comment?

Comment: @KyloRen: that was a quote from msdn(have you read it?). Yes, that's meant

Comment: @TimSchmelter ok,when i see the behave of string outputs from that perspective, the outputs are coming as expected. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [string interning](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d551d3/what-is-string-interning/).

Comment: As per my knowledge when a new value is assigned to a string reference , it will be assigned a new object of string, but that will still be assigned to same ref, z in my case, so the last statement should also print true if first one is doing so.

Comment: @KyloRen but z was never referencing y.

Comment: @parachutingturtle yes and y is never referencing x.

Comment: @KyloRen x and y are "interned" because they are known to reference the same literal at compile time. z is created at runtime.

Comment: @parachutingturtle hmmm.... and when I do string.Intern(z) in place of z then it prints true. can you explain that?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a string it creates an object (`x`).

when you create `y`, you just point to it"again", it points to the same one (has it).

When you create Z, and the do the `+=` it creates a NEW one altogether, hence, it won't match the address in the memory for the previous one.

Comment: at last assignment  a new object will be created and z is the reference to it. now since x & y should be same as y & z. shouldn't they?

Comment: @KyloRen They are not the same. They read the same, but they are references to two different places in memory.

Comment: @parachutingturtle if x and y is pointing to same string value, and so does z (eventually) why are they printing different output?